# Optimizing wp_get_attachment_image_src

Tags: gallery

I'm working on WordPress gallery. I display images with wp_get_attachment_image_src function:

```
foreach($slideshow_data['attachment_ids'] as $attachment_id) {
    $img_data = wp_get_attachment_image_src( $attachment_id, 'full' );
    echo "<img src=\"{$img_data[0]}\" width=\"{$img_data[1]}\" height=\"{$img_data[2]}\">";
}
```

Which results in over 140 database queries per page for large galleries. Of course this can be cached, but I feel that this is not correct way.

My question is, am I doing something wrong?

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Usually for gallery post types with lots of attachments, you would do it like this:

http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/get_posts#Show_attachments_for_the_current_post

Inside a "Wordpress Loop":

```
<?php
$args = array( 'post_type' => 'attachment', 'numberposts' => -1, 'post_status' => null, 'post_parent' => $post->ID ); 
$attachments = get_posts($args);
if ($attachments) {
    foreach ( $attachments as $attachment ) {
        echo apply_filters( 'the_title' , $attachment->post_title );
        the_attachment_link( $attachment->ID , false );
    }
}
?>
```